# eChart exception (NgxEchartsDirective -> InjectionToken NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG)

Tags: angular

I am using ngx-echart in angular 7 application. I am following the example in the link:
https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-e-charts-using-ngx-echarts-tutorial/#.XwSANigzaUk

But when executing (ng serve) the application, and display the component, I am getting the below error:

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgxEchartsDirective ->
> InjectionToken NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
> core)[NgxEchartsDirective -> InjectionToken NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG!
> at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
> (core.js:8896)
> at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
> at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
> at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
> (core.js:8982)
> at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
> at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
> at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
> (core.js:8982)
> at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
> at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
> (core.js:21907)
> at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({ echarts })` in your module

```
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';
import * as echarts from 'echarts';
```

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was a package installation issue. I installed only ngx-echarts.
after following the steps on the link below, I've got everything fine

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-echarts

Thank you