# How to change function to export function for decorator?

Tags: angular, serverless-framework, echarts

I have an angular project where I am importing a module using the following code in app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   ...,
   NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({
     echarts: () => import('echarts')
   }),
 ],
})
```

But when I am trying to build the project into serverless, I am getting the following regarding the above import and asking me to change it to export function so that it can be supported by decarator. How do I do that? I tried different export approaches but it is not working.

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(107,16): Error during template compile of 'ɵ0'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators
    Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

For reference, I am trying to import ngx-echarts into angular project. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-echarts

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({ echarts })
```

[eChart exception (NgxEchartsDirective -> InjectionToken NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62778609/echart-exception-ngxechartsdirective-injectiontoken-ngx-echarts-config)

Comment: I get ```No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'echarts'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.```. Any ideas?

Comment: Give this a try: `NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({ echarts: { init: echarts.init } })`